# Dice rolling simulation: landing on the edge?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, dice

I'm trying to implement my own version of a dice roller.

So far I've reached a decent result, my solution is not very flexible yet but I like the realism of the physics.

I have an issue, though: sometimes a dice lands on it's edge and it keeps that unnatural position for the rest of the time.

How can I avoid it?

I tried to tweak the physics materials, the rigid body simulation, the scale of the dice and the system gravity with no success.

Maybe I did not find the right mix or maybe I'm missing something.

I will appreciate any suggestions thanks[image: ![Dices]

Comment: just like a coin, it is arguably possible for a D6 to land on an edge, however, it would seem generally unusual.

Comment: I have found the exact problem on Unity Forum: does that solution helps? https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-box-collider-lands-on-its-edge-after-a-throw.549535/

Comment: @Andrea thanks, i've already seen it. It does not solve my issue: applying a vertical force to an object that the simulator considers 'stable' does not change things.

Moreover it seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Are they primitive cubs (form Unity) or they are your cubes with MeshCollider?

Comment: @Morasiu i've tried two kinds of colliders: simple cubes and mesh shaped colliders. Both give the same issue.

Comment: How about trying [center of mass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html) in Rigidbody?

Comment: @Morasiu it would bias the results!

Comment: You know, but maybe they are manipulating it :P Add screenhots of your rigidbody, cube mesh and that physic material.

Comment: Do you use a box collider or a mesh collider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can iterate thorugh your dice, find ones that are sleeping (Rigidbody.IsSleeping) and for those that are check the angles are not wierd (i.e. one of the angles should be close to multiplies of 90), and apply some random torque for those that are likely to stand on edge

Comment: thanks, that almost worked. I'm using small colliders on each side to determine if the die is well grounded or not. If it is not the case i add a small torque.

I should refine it, taking note of the last angular velocity the die had before sleeping and applying that value to it.

I also need to apply the force more gently (maybe incrementally during some fixed updates?) to achieve a smoother effect.


By the way it worked, thanks.